# Compare two symbolic expressions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have two symbolic expressions `a` and `b`, each consists of polynomials with basic arithmetic and small, positive, integer powers.

`simplify(a - b)` doesn't go up to 0, and my only alternative is to `subs` some random numbers into the variables and compare.

I would have expected something like expanding the expressions until there are no parentheses. Then, add all fractions into a single fraction.

I converted the data into a function which can be called as:

```
x = sym('x', [1 8], 'real')';
err = func( x ) % should be simplified to zeros

x0 = rand( size(x) )
double( subs(err, x, x0) )

simplify(err)
```

The function

```
function err_Dpsi_Dpsi2 = func(in1)
%FUNC
%    ERR_DPSI_DPSI2 = FUNC(IN1)

%    This function was generated by the Symbolic Math Toolbox version 8.4.
%    29-Dec-2020 20:03:34

x1 = in1(1,:);
x2 = in1(2,:);
x3 = in1(3,:);
x4 = in1(4,:);
x5 = in1(5,:);
x6 = in1(6,:);
x7 = in1(7,:);
x8 = in1(8,:);
t2 = x1.*x6;
t3 = x2.*x5;
t4 = x1.*x7;
t5 = x3.*x5;
t6 = x2.*x7;
t7 = x3.*x6;
t8 = -x2;
t9 = -x3;
t10 = -x6;
t11 = -x7;
t15 = x1./2.0;
t16 = x2./2.0;
t17 = x1./4.0;
t18 = x3./2.0;
t19 = x2./4.0;
t20 = x3./4.0;
t21 = x5./2.0;
t22 = x6./2.0;
t23 = x5./4.0;
t24 = x7./2.0;
t25 = x6./4.0;
t26 = x7./4.0;
t43 = x2.*7.072e+3;
t44 = x3.*7.072e+3;
t45 = x4.*7.071e+3;
t46 = x6.*7.072e+3;
t47 = x7.*7.072e+3;
t48 = x8.*7.071e+3;
t60 = x2.*x8.*-7.071e+3;
t62 = x4.*x7.*-7.071e+3;
t69 = x1.*9.999907193999999e-1;
t70 = x5.*9.999907193999999e-1;
t71 = x1.*1.0000660704;
t72 = x5.*1.0000660704;
t74 = x2.*1.0001321408;
t75 = x3.*1.0001321408;
t76 = x6.*1.0001321408;
t77 = x7.*1.0001321408;
t78 = x1.*1.0000660704;
t79 = x2.*5.000660704e-1;
t80 = x2.*1.0001321408;
t81 = x3.*5.000660704e-1;
t82 = x3.*1.0001321408;
t83 = x5.*1.0000660704;
t84 = x6.*5.000660704e-1;
t85 = x6.*1.0001321408;
t86 = x7.*5.000660704e-1;
t87 = x7.*1.0001321408;
t102 = x1.*9.999907194000001e-1;
t103 = x5.*9.999907194000001e-1;
t104 = x4.*4.999953597e-1;
t105 = x8.*4.999953597e-1;
t108 = x2.*1.000132149530596;
t109 = x3.*1.000132149530596;
t110 = x6.*1.000132149530596;
t111 = x7.*1.000132149530596;
t112 = x2.*1.000056789186827;
t113 = x3.*1.000056789186827;
t114 = x6.*1.000056789186827;
t115 = x7.*1.000056789186827;
t124 = x4.*1.000056789186827;
t125 = x8.*1.000056789186827;
t126 = x4.*9.999814388861295e-1;
t127 = x8.*9.999814388861295e-1;
t128 = x2.*1.000132149530596;
t129 = x3.*1.000132149530596;
t130 = x6.*1.000132149530596;
t131 = x7.*1.000132149530596;
t139 = x4.*2.500307147434136e-1;
t140 = x8.*2.500307147434136e-1;
t141 = x2.*1.000056789186827;
t142 = x3.*1.000056789186827;
t144 = x4.*1.000056789186827;
t145 = x6.*1.000056789186827;
t146 = x7.*1.000056789186827;
t148 = x8.*1.000056789186827;
t157 = x2.*x8.*(-2.500307147434136e-1);
t158 = x4.*x7.*(-2.500307147434136e-1);
t159 = x4.*9.999814388861297e-1;
t160 = x8.*9.999814388861297e-1;
t12 = -t3;
t13 = -t4;
t14 = -t7;
t27 = t2./4.0;
t28 = t3./4.0;
t29 = t4./4.0;
t30 = t5./4.0;
t31 = t6./4.0;
t32 = t7./4.0;
t33 = t8+x1;
t34 = t9+x1;
t35 = t10+x5;
t36 = t11+x5;
t37 = -t16;
t38 = -t18;
t39 = -t20;
t40 = -t22;
t41 = -t24;
t42 = -t26;
t52 = t6.*7.072e+3;
t53 = t48.*x2;
t54 = t7.*7.072e+3;
t55 = t45.*x6;
t56 = t48.*x3;
t57 = t45.*x7;
t58 = -t45;
t59 = -t48;
t88 = -t74;
t89 = -t75;
t90 = -t76;
t91 = -t77;
t92 = -t80;
t93 = -t79;
t94 = -t82;
t95 = -t81;
t96 = -t85;
t97 = -t84;
t98 = -t87;
t99 = -t86;
t116 = -t108;
t117 = -t109;
t118 = -t110;
t119 = -t111;
t120 = -t112;
t121 = -t113;
t122 = -t114;
t123 = -t115;
t132 = -t128;
t133 = -t129;
t134 = -t130;
t135 = -t131;
t136 = t6.*2.500660747652978e-1;
t137 = t7.*2.500660747652978e-1;
t143 = -t139;
t147 = -t140;
t149 = t140.*x2;
t150 = t139.*x6;
t151 = t140.*x3;
t152 = t139.*x7;
t153 = -t141;
t154 = -t142;
t155 = -t145;
t156 = -t146;
t49 = -t28;
t50 = -t29;
t51 = -t32;
t61 = -t54;
t63 = t43+t58;
t64 = t44+t58;
t65 = t46+t59;
t66 = t47+t59;
t67 = t2+t5+t6+t12+t13+t14;
t138 = -t137;
t161 = t15+t38+t93+t104;
t162 = t15+t37+t95+t104;
t163 = t21+t41+t97+t105;
t164 = t21+t40+t99+t105;
t169 = t71+t89+t116+t124;
t170 = t71+t88+t117+t124;
t171 = t72+t91+t118+t125;
t172 = t72+t90+t119+t125;
t173 = t78+t92+t133+t144;
t174 = t78+t94+t132+t144;
t175 = t83+t96+t135+t148;
t176 = t83+t98+t134+t148;
t177 = t69+t120+t121+t126;
t178 = t70+t122+t123+t127;
t179 = t102+t153+t154+t159;
t180 = t103+t155+t156+t160;
t68 = 1.0./t67;
t73 = t27+t30+t31+t49+t50+t51;
t106 = t52+t55+t56+t60+t61+t62;
t165 = t161.^2;
t166 = t162.^2;
t167 = t163.^2;
t168 = t164.^2;
t182 = t136+t138+t150+t151+t157+t158;
t100 = 1.0./t73;
t107 = 1.0./t106;
t181 = t165+t166+t167+t168;
t183 = 1.0./t182;
t101 = t100.^2;
t184 = t183.^2;
err_Dpsi_Dpsi2 = [t181.*(t35.*t68.*t100-t36.*t68.*t100)+t101.*t181.*(t25+t42),-t100.*t169+t100.*t174+t169.*t183-t174.*t183-t101.*t181.*(t23+t42)+t181.*t184.*(t140-x7.*2.500660747652978e-1)+t36.*t68.*t100.*t181+t66.*t107.*t181.*t183.*1.0,-t100.*t170+t100.*t173+t170.*t183-t173.*t183-t181.*t184.*(t140-x6.*2.500660747652978e-1)+t101.*t181.*(t23-t25)-t35.*t68.*t100.*t181-t65.*t107.*t181.*t183.*1.0,t100.*t177-t100.*t179-t177.*t183+t179.*t183+t181.*(t65.*t107.*t183.*9.998585972850678e-1-t66.*t107.*t183.*9.998585972850678e-1)-t181.*t184.*(x6.*2.500307147434136e-1-x7.*2.500307147434136e-1),-t181.*(t33.*t68.*t100-t34.*t68.*t100)-t101.*t181.*(t19+t39),-t100.*t171+t100.*t176+t171.*t183-t176.*t183+t101.*t181.*(t17+t39)-t181.*t184.*(t139-x3.*2.500660747652978e-1)-t34.*t68.*t100.*t181-t64.*t107.*t181.*t183.*1.0,-t100.*t172+t100.*t175+t172.*t183-t175.*t183+t181.*t184.*(t139-x2.*2.500660747652978e-1)-t101.*t181.*(t17-t19)+t33.*t68.*t100.*t181+t63.*t107.*t181.*t183.*1.0,t100.*t178-t100.*t180-t178.*t183+t180.*t183-t181.*(t63.*t107.*t183.*9.998585972850678e-1-t64.*t107.*t183.*9.998585972850678e-1)+t181.*t184.*(x2.*2.500307147434136e-1-x3.*2.500307147434136e-1)];
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the equations you're trying to subtract and simplify?

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: The following variable should simplify to 0: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HOzkiGKSQV1w-miu4w_tJZmPfRwsYnGc

Comment: I converted it into a function.

Comment: So you are saying that this works correctly except when you have nearly 200 terms? Or you didn’t try to make a minimal version of the problem? Minimal versions always give insights. They tend to point out the problem. Remove terms and components until it starts working correctly. What did you remove that made it work? Can you reproduce the problem only with that component? Keep removing other components, to find the truly minimal set. Now we can clearly see what is causing the problem. This is how debugging works.

Comment: I posted an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for

```
num = numden( err ) % convert to rational polynomial, and we care only about the numerator
collect( num ) % cancel terms--not needed, numden does some version of simplify
```

My example, though, wasn't good. For some reason, there are precision issues. I thought that symbolic used exact arithmetic, but I didn't look into that. However, if I use variables instead of finite precision coefficients, then it outputs zeros.

Comment: Things like `9.999907193999999e-1` in your code should maybe have been 1? But yes, if you enter finite precision numbers you already introduced rounding errors, you can no longer do only symbolic math.

Comment: The code is auto generated, so I don't know what it should have been. Originally, I used coeff like 0.707107. When I say finite precision, I mean that matlab can convert it to a rational and perform all the calc in exact arithmetic. Maybe I need to do the conversion explicitly. In general, there shouldn't be a problem since if the expression is correct for an arbitrary var, then it should be correct for a specific number.